# Meaning of ' in SQL Pivot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Can someone explain me the meaning of the ' symbol in the second block? I found this old post dealing with pivot and the set @query is put into these symbols' while the first one is not (the select @cols). What is the meaning of that? Why it needs to be done like that?

[Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Week) 
                    from yt
                    group by Week
                    order by Week
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT store,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select store, week, xCount
                from yt
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(xCount)
                for week in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

Comment: "Why it needs to be done like that?"  when dealing with a dynamic number of columns in a pivot, dynamic SQL must be used.  The @Cols simply is the list of columns the user wants to pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second block is using dynamic query evaluation. The `'` symbols are simply string literal delimiters.

Comment: Ok, so easy. Thank you